# How to send the section number to function?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i try to get my section number to a function. i am using

> `-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

i try to reload the section in the table from this func

```
-(void)headerButtonPushed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Heder pressed: %d",[sender tag]);
    if (_state == [sender tag])
        _state = kAllSectionClose;
    else
        _state = [sender tag];
    // Here i need to reload the specific section
}
```

i know i have the tag but the function i thing i need to use is

```
[tableView reloadSections:indexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

and for that i need index path..

i try

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0];
```

but i got error
some one?

Comment: here Your question does not explain what you really want...? try to specific...!!!so that we could give answer...

Answer (score 0):

The indexPath required isn't the indexPath of the row (which is the code example you're giving on the last line above), the indexPath is the index of the section you want to refresh/reload.

Do you know the index of the section you need to reload? Try hardcoding it to see if that works. If (for whatever reason) you can't determine the section you're in, you could always reload the entire tableview: `[tableView reloadData];`